# ImportError: cannot import name ModuleA

Tags: python, module, import, importerror

I have the following stacktrace when I try to import ModuleA:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
  File "menu.py", line 9, in <module>                                                       
    from tmserver import Module1                                                          
  File "~/tmserver/Module1.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                           
    from tmserver.PackageA import ModuleA                                             
  File "~/tmserver/Package1/ModuleA.py", line 8, in <module>                                                               
    from tmserver.Package2 import Module2                                               
  File "~/tmserver/Package2/Module2.py", line 15, in <module>                                                                
    from tmserver.Package3 import Module3                                                      
  File "~/tmserver/Package3/Module3.py", line 5, in <module>                                                                        
    from tmserver.PackageA import ModuleA                                            
ImportError: cannot import name ModuleA
```

Is this because it's importing ModuleA again/recursively?

Comment: Maybe you have two different files called tmserver? You can add some prints to debug that, along with sys.path... Still weird.

Comment: See section 'Circular imports' here http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm  for a good explanation of what is going wrong in your setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would seem like the logical conclusion; perhaps if you posted samples of the code you were running you'd be able to get a better reply?

Comment: +1 but there is no need to post more code. It's all in the stacktrace. On importing ModuleA, before the rest of the imports are finished (and thus ModuleA wasn't fully loaded) it gets to try to import ModuleA again. Infinite recursion.