# Importing the django.test does not work

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

As it is failing to import django.test module, unit test does not work.

```
>>> import django.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\__init__.py", line 5, in <mod
le>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 21, in <modu
e>
    from django.test import signals
ImportError: cannot import name signals
>>>
```

Please some one help me in resolving it. I am using django version 1.3

Comment: Can you please provide more info on your install? Did you check that the signals.py file exists in the C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\ folder?

Comment: Are you running a shell using `python manage.py shell` ?

Comment: Please separate `code` from question.  Please **Edit** your question to indent only the `code` and not indent the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution explained here:
[ImportError: cannot import name signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983100/importerror-cannot-import-name-signals)
worked for me.

They added these lines to the test:

```
from django.core import management;
import myapp.settings as settings;
management.setup_environ(settings)
```